# Filter results wordpress by ancestor page

Tags: wordpress, search, filter, parent, ancestor

I have this kind of structure

```
- Page A
---- Page A1
---- Page A2
---- Page Axx
- Page B
---- Page B1
---- Page B2
---- Page Bxx
- Page C
...
```

***Ok you get it :)***

Now I'd like to filter the search results of page by ancestor.

Result page should be :

```
Page ancestor B
- PAge B2
- Page B5

Page ancestor D
- Page D4
- Page D6
```

Do you think it's possible ?

```
add_action( "pre_get_posts", "custom_search_order" );

function custom_search_order( $query )
{
    if ( $query -> is_search() )
    {
        $query -> set( "meta_key", "service" ); // Your custom field ID.
        $query -> set( "orderby", "meta_value" ); // Or "meta_value_num".
        $query -> set( "order", "ASC" ); // Or "DESC".
    }
}
```

This code isn't working fine at this time.

Comment: So in the search results you want to show all matching pages but hierarchically ordered?

Comment: Hi, yes totally, second the page ancestor.

Comment: What is happening if the search matches a child but not the parent? Should the parent also visible in this case?